# What is the difference between {{-- --}} and {{ }} in laravel framework blade files?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

In the laravel framework we can use blade to add PHP code in html file.

We are using both `{{-- --}}` and `{!! !!}` syntax in blade files of Laravel framework .

What is the basic difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

`{{-- --}}` is used to include comments, `{!! !!}` is used to display a variable without escaping it, for example to display html content.

Answer (score 1):

`{{-- --}}` is to create comments in your blade files.

`{!! !!}` is for displaying data without escaping it.

You can read about those in the laravel docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#comments
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 0):

The first `{{-- --}}` is used for Blade comments, it will not be displayed in HTML.

The second `{!! !!}` is used to display unescaped data.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{-- This comment will not be present in the rendered HTML --}}

{!! it is used for escape html while rendering !!}
```